# Error: Message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've made a popup view, with a `UIButton` on it which closes the view. Whenever I put on the button, the program quits with this message: `[MTPopupWindow performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x84675f0`
Here is the [**header file**](http://pastebin.com/Q86GpHan) and [**source file**](http://pastebin.com/Nk6sVT2u) to use the class I use this line of code:

```
[MTPopupWindow showWindowWithContent:@"Some text here" insideView:self.view];
```

I thought that there was something wrong with deallocating my objects too soon but since I'm using `ARC` I'm not sure what is causing this problem. I think the problem is in this line of code:

```
[self.closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopupWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I don't see anything wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should have known there was a problem when you wrote this:

```
// Cast to void because we don't use the result (otherwise compiler warning)
```

Since you don't use the result, ARC believes that it's free to insert a release on your object after that line, which means the object is getting deallocated way early.

There are a number of ways around this; take a look at things like `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` or having the caller of your popup window hold a strong reference to it.

Comment: I can't find anything usefull from the NS_RETURNS_RETAINED could you give me an example how I can solve this problem?